# How to render the field from custom block in node.twig

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, blocks

I want to render the custom field from my block in node.twig. As I understand I have to expose the fields from Block to Node variables.

How to realize that?

Answer (score 1):

A node should not have access to a block unless you've done something to add the block to the node. A block can have access to node fields, though (the reverse).

To do what you're talking about I would recommend adding that block to the node in some way. For example:

if you want to add a block as a field in a node:
https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldblock
I would normally use Display suite to then output this block as I want, where I want. But you can also access it via twig template at this point just as you would any other field.

if you're building with paragraphs:
https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraph_blocks

Comment: Yes, you need a reference from node to block. Additional to the examples provided it's possible without installing a module. D8 supports referencing any entities, also custom blocks. Twig is also not necessarily needed. If the block has more fields than you want to display, you can render the block in a custom view mode.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I want to programmatically display the field of a block in a node, and not the field of a node in a block. I need it for the convenience of updating the dollar rate, and then do mathematical operations with this value. Maybe I'm moving in the wrong direction and Drupal has a more convenient solution? How else can you edit the dynamic value in the admin panel?

Comment: I need something like this https://www.drupal.org/project/global_content